# How to prove the following statement about limit?

Tags: limits, analysis

> Suppose $u_n=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}u_{n+i}^2$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}u_i$ exists. Then $u_n=0$ for each $n$.

I have proved that $u_n=u_{n+1}^2+u_{n+1}$. It is easy to show that $u_n$ converge to $0$, the hint of the question is to prove that $u_n\sim 1/n$ with Stolz theorem but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: We have $u_{n+1}=$ $\frac { 2u_n}{1+\sqrt {1+4u_n}}$ $\ge \frac {2u_n}{1+(1+2u_n)}$ $=\frac {u_n}{1+u_n}$.... I am rusty, but is this sufficient  (when every  $u_n>0$) for $\sum_n u_n$ to diverge?

Answer (score 1):

Taking up from your observation of $u_n=u_{n+1}+u_{n+1}^2$, this implies that 
    $1= \frac{(u_{n+1})}{u_n} + {u_{n+1}}\frac{(u_{n+1})}{u_n}$ $\Rightarrow 1 \geq u_{n+1}+1$ (from convergence of $\sum u_{n}$). Which implies $\forall $n$, u_n \leq 0$. Again, from the question, the very first equation tells us each $u_n$ is sum of square terms, means each $u_n \geq 0$, this completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $u_n>0$,
$$
\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{u_{n}}=\frac{u_n-u_{n+1}}{u_n \cdot u_{n+1}}=\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1-\frac{u_{n+1}^2}{u_n}
$$
Since
$$
0\le \frac{u_{n+1}^2}{u_n}\le u_n\rightarrow 0
$$
we have
$$
\lim nu_n=\lim \frac{1}{\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{u_n}}=1
$$
which means $u_n\sim \frac{1}{n}$.